# How do I combine back buttons for Screens and WebView into one in React Native using React Navigation package?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, back-button

I'm learning navigation in React Native, and can't figure out way how to conditionally use one Back Button.
Wanted behaviour would be like this - if user navigate between screens, he can press Go Back button, but if one of the screens contains WebView and he already visited few pages there, user would go back through this webview pages first, then Screens. Hope that makes sense.
Something like that: Screen A <- Screen B <- Screen C with WebView <- Webview Page 1 <- Webview Page 2

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1imzG.png)

**AppScreen**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Pressable, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import WebViewScreen from './src/screens/WebViewScreen';
import ParamsScreen from './src/screens/ParamsScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={
          ({navigation}) => {}
        }>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{title: 'Customized Header Home'}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="WebView Screen"
          component={WebViewScreen}
          options={({navigation, route}) => ({
            title: 'Webview',
            headerLeft: () => (
              <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                <Text style={{color: 'blue'}}>Go Back within Screens</Text>
              </Pressable>
            ),
          })}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Params Screen" component={ParamsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default App;
```

**WebViewScreen**

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator, Button} from 'react-native';
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

const WebViewScreen = ({navigation, route}) => {
  const webViewRef = useRef<WebView>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{flex: 0, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text>WebView Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go Back within WebView"
          onPress={() => webViewRef.current?.goBack()}
        />
      </View>
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://google.com'}}
        startInLoadingState
        ref={webViewRef}
        renderLoading={() => (
          <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
          </View>
        )}
        allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures
        onNavigationStateChange={navState => {}}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default WebViewScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

At the moment I've managed to have two separate working buttons, but it would be much better to have one back button in the header.
I was playing with Screen **options** and **onNavigationStateChange** params, and  but kind of got lost there.

I guess I would need some kind of function like this:

```
  const goBack = () => {
if (webViewRef.current) {
  webViewRef.current.goBack();
} else {
  navigation.goBack();
}
```

};

but not sure how to integrate it with Stack.Navigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior by using a combination of `headerLeft` and `onNavigationStateChange` in your `WebViewScreen`. Here's a modified version of your `WebViewScreen` that should help you implement the combined back functionality:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator, Button } from 'react-native';
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const WebViewScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const webViewRef = useRef();

  const handleNavigationStateChange = (navState) => {
    // Check if WebView can go back
    const canGoBack = navState.canGoBack;

    // Update the header left button based on WebView navigation
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <View style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
          <Button
            onPress={() => {
              if (canGoBack) {
                // If WebView can go back, go back in WebView
                webViewRef.current.goBack();
              } else {
                // If WebView cannot go back, go back in the navigation stack
                navigation.goBack();
              }
            }}
            title="Go Back"
            color="blue"
          />
        </View>
      ),
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ flex: 0, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>WebView Screen</Text>
      </View>
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: 'https://google.com' }}
        startInLoadingState
        ref={webViewRef}
        renderLoading={() => (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
          </View>
        )}
        allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures
        onNavigationStateChange={handleNavigationStateChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default WebViewScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

In this code, the `handleNavigationStateChange` function checks if the WebView can go back (`canGoBack`). It then updates the `headerLeft` button accordingly. If the WebView can go back, the button will trigger `webViewRef.current.goBack()`, otherwise, it will trigger `navigation.goBack()` to go back in the navigation stack.

This way, you have a single "Go Back" button in the header that handles both WebView and screen navigation.

Comment: That works. Thank you!

May I ask what would be considered in your opinion as a better practice: 
Styling default header bar in <Stack.Navigator> to have same style across all Screens and WebView pages, or building navigation header as separate component to be displayed across all screens?

Comment: Great, for a simple and consistent design across screens, styling the default header might be sufficient. If you have complex styling requirements, want to reuse the header across multiple screens, or have specific behavior for the header, a custom component is a good choice. Ultimately, choose the approach that aligns with your project's requirements, scalability, and your personal preference in terms of code organization and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with `WebView`, I normally use React Native for Android/iOS dev, still, I have an idea that might work.

Just do this ( hope you know how to use React Context, if not comment it, I will update the answer ) :

1. Make a useState array in App() `const [history, setHistory] = useState([])`
2. Wrap your app with `Context` and put `history` and `setHistory` in `value` attribute.
3. Now, every time you navigate to a new page, just store the Page's name in array with `history.push('WebPage name')`, this way you can know if there are pages in background and which and how many.
4. Than everytime you use go back button, you can check
   `history.length?` to see if array has any element, if yes you can do go back to last webpage by `webViewRef.current?.goBack()`, else you can do `navigation.goBack()` to navigate to last screen.

Overall it will look like this :
// go Back button

```
<Button
    title="Go Back within WebView"
    onPress={() => history.length? // short hand if-else 
        webViewRef.current?.goBack() : // if yes than go back to last webpage
        navigation.goBack() // if no, go back to screen
    }
        />
```

Using Context is really easy, comment if you don't get anything, I will update my answer. Also upvote if this helps, just need a few more reputations :)